# Twitch API Live Callback Service

Tags: php, api, callback, twitch

I am integrating the Twitch user account API into my platform and had a look through the API to see if there was a callback section of some sort to send an update to my server when a user starts streaming, but I can't seem to find any reference for one.

Is there currently any services that offer this sort of thing? If not, what would be the best way of running regular checks on all of my users in my Database to see when they are streaming, of course doing this alone would kill the server with database queries, so I'm stuck as to where to go now.

What I am looking to do is receive a callback and then create a post in a social feed that the user has started streaming.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussions at the links below, the API doesn't support webhooks and won't anytime soon. Instead, they expect you to use polling. Basically you would set up a worker process that makes requests periodically, such as every five minutes, then creates appropriate social feed posts, etc. You can batch them together if you have a bunch of channels to check (exaple from from the github issue):

`https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?channel=riotgames,dota2ti,machinima,esltv_hearthstone`

https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/issues/211

https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/notifications-using-twitch-api-and-php/1009